# How to access web server through an ad-hoc connection?

Tags: networking, connection, webserver, localhost, adhoc

If I were to connect my iphone to my apache server through an ad hoc connection, how would I access my apache server?  What would the URL be for me to access my server?  My guess would be that localhost should do it however, I am not aware of networking protocols and how they work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your best bet would most likely be to:

1) connect both devices to a single wireless network/router

2) determine your computer's ip address via [ifconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig), or ipconfig (for windows)

3) then type http://your_ip_address:your_servers_port/ in your mobile browser
   for example http://192.168.1.1:8888/

Also this is not considered Ad-Hoc, but this is a simple, easy to setup, and portable solution.

Comment: Yes, this may be so, however if I wish to use an Ad-Hoc connection between my iphone and web server how can I access my web server through my iphone.  If I did "http://localhost" will that work?

Comment: No that wont work. localhost is just a loopback to the device your on. Trust me this is the solution you want anything else would be harder to do and not as useful.

Comment: I am searching for a solution that utilizes the adhoc connection

Comment: Although OP was looking adhoc solution. The one you gave is way better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did that kind of thing with an iPad:

Like Gunnar Hoffman said:

1) Get your **computer's ip**, get **the port number** on which your apache runs

2) Browse *http://ip:port* with your iOS device (where you substitute ip with the ip of your computer and port with the port on which apache runs the server)

If you use the **built-in webserver** (on Mac OS X; which is configurable through the system preferences) you are presented the url of the server (also in the system preferences).

I personally used this "technique" to transfer files to an iPad via WiFi.